# Цикл, getchar(), putchar() и символ новой строки (язык Си)

Tags: c

Я хочу написать программу которая считывает 10 символов включая символы новой строки и выводит эти символы, все 10 символов одновременно. Но моя программа работает не так как я от неё ожидаю, сразу же после нажатия клавиши Enter она выводит уже введённые символы. Возможно ли это исправить используя именно getchar() и putchar()? Почему символ новой строки оказывается своего рода особенным в такой программе?

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        int count = 0;
        char ch = 0;
        while (count < 10) {
            ch = getchar();
            putchar(ch);
            count++;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему символ новой строки оказывается своего рода особенным в такой программе?

Символ новой строки сам по себе не является особенным для программы. Особенной является клавиша <kbd>Enter</kbd> для того ПО которое стоит между этой программой и клавиатурой.

Т.е. в данном примере программа будет выполняться до тех пор пока не встретит первый вызов `getchar()` после чего она остановится и отдаст управление другой программе (точнее в современных системах целому набору программ: ОС, драйверу терминала, эмулятору терминала, «окну консоли»). Затем это ПО будет обрабатывать нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре, отображая вводимые символы на экран, и удаляя их по <kbd>backspace</kbd>'у пока не будет нажата определённая клавиша с говорящим названием «ввод». Далее это ПО передаёт **всю** (обычно так, хотя оно может передать и только её часть) введённую строку пользовательской программе, программа сохраняет её в *буфере потока ввода*, просто отбирает один символ из этой строки, возвращает его в `getchar()` и продолжает выполнение. При следующем вызове `getchar()` из той же, уже полученной, строки вернётся ещё один символ, итд. Когда строка в буфере программы закончится, программа снова обратится за новой порцией к системному ПО.

> Возможно ли это исправить используя именно getchar() и putchar()?

В этом конкретном случае программа выводит символы сразу как получает их, т.е. независимо от того, получила ли, она от системного ПО `1` символ или `200`, она выведет их как только получит и запросит снова, если оказалось, что их было меньше `10`. Так что нужно просто накапливать все символы во временном буфере, а затем вывести все их разом. Вобзих чертах получится что-то такое:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SZ 10

int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    char buf[BUF_SZ];
    char ch = 0;

    while (count < BUF_SZ) {
        ch = getchar();
        count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<BUF_SZ; i++) {
        putchar(buf[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```